# MDADM RAID1 Home Server System disk error: incrementally starting raid arrays mdadm: Create user root not found

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

I'm not sure what else to check. Everything below looks sane to me but the system hangs on boot. This is a home server with four disks crammed into a Dell OP620. Each pair of disks are assembled as RAID1: `/` and `data`. The failed array is `/`, hence the inability to boot.

The full error, which repeats indefinitely on the console, is:

```
incrementally starting raid arrays
mdadm: Create user root not found 
mdadm: create group disk not found 
incrementally started raid arrays
```

A similar screenshot is available [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/612956/ubuntu-14-04-mdadm-issues-on-boot). This system was running fine until the last restart. The array assembles fine from a Puppy Linux rescue USB:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

`fdiisk` shows the available disks:

```
# fdisk -l|grep GB
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
Disk /dev/md127: 3000.5 GB, 3000457494528 bytes
Disk /dev/md126: 317.9 GB, 317938532352 bytes
```

Followed by `blkid` displaying UUIDs:

```
# blkid
/dev/md126: UUID="fc836940-3c99-4f64-8751-decc9629abc5" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md0: UUID="2b00d6da-aa0e-4295-a1bb-822f4224815b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="908ccc1f-cb70-4d3e-9d81-43b8e0f519ff" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="3a052c52-593f-47d5-8606-cb818619c50b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="8GB_BLACK_P" UUID="1CE1-AF11" TYPE="vfat"
```

and I can mount the `md126` device with:

```
mount /dev/md126 /mnt/tmp
```

My (previously working) fstab file is:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/md1 during installation
UUID=fc836940-3c99-4f64-8751-decc9629abc5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=2b00d6da-aa0e-4295-a1bb-822f4224815b none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/mapper/3TB_RAID--1--LVM-lvol0      /data   ext4    nosuid,auto     0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this problem too.  I noticed that your md is numbered md126  which is usually a random number made up at boot time, not the number from `mdadm.conf`

In `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, various things refer to both `/dev/md??` and `UUID=.....`

Both are needed.  If the machine is booting up with a random md??? number every time, initrd will struggle to find the raid and go in an endless loop.

I had to change these numbers because I re-created my md device.

`update-grub` grabs the `md?` number from what's currently running in `/proc/mdstats` and puts it into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

`update-initramfs` grabs the `md?` number from the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file and puts it into `/boot/initrd___`  Both have to match.

When you boot via a rescue disk, `/dev/md...` is just whatever random number the rescue disk makes up.  This is different to the `md...` number in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

What I did was run  `mdadm --stop /dev/md...` on all the disks.  Then ran...

```
mdadm --assemble --config=/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf --run
cat /proc/mdstat   # To check that the numbers are correct.
update-grub
```

If you needed to change `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, also run `update-initramfs`

Looks like your fstab says `/ was on /dev/md1 during installation`;  that's the number that may be in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Xen virtual machine that actually does not have any RAID configuration (but the Dom0/host machine has).

The actual error are not the RAID, but you need to scroll the log up a bit, and on my machine the actual error is that there is no disks (or network adapter/vif) present, so there is some problem with the Xenbus providing the devices to the virtual machine:

```
 [  272.220880] xenbus_probe_frontend: Timeout connecting to device: device/vbd/51714 (local state 1, remote state 1)
 [  272.221595] xenbus_probe_frontend: Timeout connecting to device: device/vbd/51713 (local state 1, remote state 1)
 [  272.222102] xenbus_probe_frontend: Timeout connecting to device: device/vif/0 (local state 1, remote state 1)
```

I solved the issue by rebooting the host machine. After that the created xen virtual machines booted normally again, and saw all the devices.