# Upgrade 12.04->14.04 broke mdadm RAID10. Boot stops

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, raid, mdadm

Server was an Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and was running just fine. All four drives in server are SATA spin-drives.

```
/dev/md0 - swap RAID10: sda1, sdb1, sdc1, sdd1
/dev/md1 - root RAID10: sda2, sdb2, sdc2, sdd2
/dev/md2 - /d01 RAID05: sda5, sdb5, sdc5, sdd5
```

Upgraded the OS to 14.04.02 via `do-release-upgrade` and it seemed to upgrade just fine. No errors were observed. However I now get the following error message during boot:

```
incrementally starting raid arrays
mdadm: Create user root not found 
mdadm: create group disk not found 
incrementally started raid arrays
```

...which just repeats over and over again.

The mdadm arrays are fine. Super-blocks are in sync. I can boot to *recover a broken system* via a CD/USB and reassemble and access the arrays and their data with no problems. I just can't get the OS to boot.

I have modified the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and changed the device names from `/dev/md/X` to `/dev/mdX`, and then re-ran `update-initramfs` and then `update-grub`. Both executed fine but still no luck in booting.

Just some of the suggestions I have tried:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/ubuntu-how-do-the-md-devices-get-assembled-at-bootup
- https://serverfault.com/questions/593734/mdadm-boot-error-incrementally-starting-raid-array-ubuntu-server-14-04
- http://www.larrystendebach.com/fixing-incrementally-starting-raid-arrays/

I have tried performing many many of the suggestions found on this subject matter. None have worked. I'm at a loss as to what do to next. I believe this is a boot configuration (initramfs) problem. But I cannot seem to fix it. I would prefer to not have to reload and reconfigure the OS. Anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas, you may have tried these already, but here you go.

After building new system, be sure `mdadm.conf` references the correct disk/array ids.

If you make changes to `mdadm.conf`, you need to update the boot loader:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday.  My fix is here...

[MDADM RAID1 Home Server System disk error: incrementally starting raid arrays mdadm: Create user root not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529228/mdadm-raid1-home-server-system-disk-error-incrementally-starting-raid-arrays-md/609434#609434)

If you're running `update-grub` from the "recover from a broken system" you have to make sure that the currently mounted drives in `/proc/mdstat` are correct first.

Double check the `UUID=???` `/dev/md?` numbers in all these files...

```
/etc/fstab
/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

I found out by making my own `/boot/initrd...` file and changing the scripts there. If you still have problems put a "mount" statement at the top of the `mdadm-functions` file and `update-initramfs` again to see if the drives have been mounted when it's stuck in that loop.